# change user agent of customtabs in android

Tags: android, webview, chrome-custom-tabs, android-customtabs

I am using customtabs in android app. I want to load desktop view of website in it. So I want to change the user agent of customtabs. How to do this? I have done this in WebView but could not find any method to change user agent of customtabs.

Comment: What have you done so far to accomplish your goal? Where are you stuck? Can you provide sample code and error messages if available?

Answer (score 0):

Changing user agent is not possible with customtabs, and would be hard to implement. Setting request-desktop-site for a custom tab is not available either.

The justification for this feature is confusing to me: why is it better to have desktop version in custom tabs and mobile version in regular Chrome? What should happen when menu item "Open in Chrome" is selected?

Comment: I want to open [WhatsApp Web](https://web.whatsapp.com) in mobile. As this site show QR code only in desktop version of site. In mobile version it is showing different content.

Comment: Have you asked whatsappweb to provide a flavor of URL for desktop viewing?

Customtabs would be a bad place to apply workarounds for cases when the website owner resists to show the right content. Customtabs is a special UI for Chrome plus a warmup service. Interception on the network level is out of scope for it.